# C# .NET Button with Bootstrap Modal Doesn't fire in server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

In my .net C# project I use repeater to display data, 
For each repeater item I have a "EDIT" button that should pops up a modal with the relevant data.
I want the button would display the Modal and also load the relevant data from the server
I tried to use:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="btn_done2"  CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg"     OnCommand="loadEventToLoad" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">EDIT</asp:LinkButton>
```

The Result is: only the modal popsup and the Command doesn't fire at all
any way to fix it without make the load from the client side?

Comment: you can make the button do only the postback to load the data, and then in your javascriptCode or Via Startupscript you can place a call to open the popup,this call will be rendered from the server side after the button is clicked where you know that you want to show the popup (you can have a literalControl within the document.ready event and write a javascript call to open the popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the contents of your modal, then you will need to put an UpdatePanel in the modal first. Then, you can wrap your Button in an UpdatePanel and you should be able to debug the postback and modify the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a href without runat = sever tag. This way you can open up without firing a server side event.